# Disjoint union topology on disjoint subspaces is the same as the the subspace topology of their union?

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering about the following question:

> Let $Y_\alpha\subseteq X$ be disjoint and $U\subseteq\bigcup_\alpha Y_\alpha$.
> **Question:** Is $U$ open in $\bigcup_\alpha Y_\alpha$ $\iff$ each $U\cap Y_\alpha$ is open in $Y_\alpha$?

It's easy to see that the answer is positive under the additional assumption that all $Y_\alpha$'s be open in $X$. But without that, I can still prove the "$\Rightarrow$'' part. I was wondering if "$\Leftarrow$" also holds generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as I was writing the question, I found a trivial counterexample to the general question: Take $Y_x := \{x\}$ for $x\in X$ and take any non-open set $U$ of $X$.